# Running multiple commands in Sublime Text 2 build system

Tags: latex, build-process, sublimetext2

Does anyone know of a way of running multiple commands in ST2's build system, or if not, how can I make it run a bashscript (where I'll put the commands)?

I'm attempting to use sublime text 2's build system to compile a latex document.
At present I am manually running a bash script with multiple commands but it would be more convenient to be able to build directly from ST2.

I have tried:

```
{
"osx":
{
    "cmd": ["Compile"]
}
}
```

but I get the error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'Compile.sh']]
[dir:  /Users/jackmedley/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

from ST2
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools). Installation instructions are in the GitHub readme, and it's worked splendidly for me so far.

Comment: how does it answer the question?
Edit: sorry, I was probably too rude, it's ok to help him with latex, as he mentioned it, but googlers are here for the shell script running, that's why I missed the value in your answer.

Comment: No worries. I wanted to help get LaTeX running even though I didn't know the answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OS X guy, but I just fiddled with this on Ubuntu Linux, and you have to specify the executable to parse your script. I would modify what you tried like this:

```
{
    "osx":
    {
        "cmd": ["sh", "yourscript.sh"]
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of `sh`, you can use `bash`, or `zsh`, or whatever. It might be necessary to provide the full path like `/bin/bash`, but it wasn't for me.